# Wait Synchronous callback?

Tags: java, android, movesense

Suppose I have the following code:

```
private void getResource(String mac, String resource) {
int threadID = android.os.Process.myTid();

Log.e( "", "Marker 1" );
Mds.builder().build(mContext).get(SCHEME_PREFIX + mac + resource, null, new MdsResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String data, MdsHeader header) {
        Log.e( "", "Marker 2" );
        
        int callbackTID = android.os.Process.myTid();
        if( callbackTID == threadID) {
            Log.e("", "Same Thread");
        }

        else{
            Log.e("", "Different Thread");
        }
      }
  });

Log.e( "", "Marker 3" );
}
```

It seems like the callback I specified in `new MdsResponseListener` is executed in the **same** thread that made the overall function call to `get(...)`, because `threadID` and `callbackTID` are identical.

However, The log clearly shows, that `"Marker 3"` is printed *before* `"Marker 2"` which, from my understanding, tells me that this is an asynchronous callback after all. How can this be? Im quite new to java (and android) so maybe I am missing some crucial base knowledege here.

How could one implement a method for waiting on the callback? I have tried it with a `CoundDownLatch` which simply counts down in the `onSuccess` method and awaits before the `"Marker 3"`log print, but as I expected, I got stuck because apparently the callback runs in the same thread as the one waiting.

Comment: check if there is a non async get function .. place everything in a new Thread and it will update ui Thread..

Comment: unfortunatley, there is no synchronized get function. I tried using the async get in a  thread, the callback however, is still executed in the main thread.

Comment: Well its a bit dirty but you could start a timer with a countdown timer at the start of get which at the 0 it will do marker 3... not recommanded but its solution..

Comment: This would not solve the problem. I would need to wait on the callback before returning from my function. I dont quite understand how a timer would achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read about asynchronous programming and how it works.

Example 1:

```
       Log.e( "", "Marker 1" );
    Mds.builder().build(mContext).get(SCHEME_PREFIX + mac + resource, null, new MdsResponseListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String data, MdsHeader header) {
            Log.e( "", "Marker 2" );
            doSomething() // Your method call when response is ready

      });

    private void doSomething() {
     Log.e( "", "Marker 3" );
   }

    }
```

Example 2 ( RxJava )

```
Obserable.create( source -> 
Mds.builder().build(mContext).get(SCHEME_PREFIX + mac + resource, null, new MdsResponseListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String data, MdsHeader header) {
     source.onNext(data)
     source.onComplete()
  });
)
```

Then subscribe to this observable and You can manipalute subscribeOn / observeOn.

> NOTE: This is only pseudo code and shows how it can be done.

Comment: I know its late, but you were right. I didnt even understand the fundamentals of Rx at the time ;)